# my game is freezing up so much after ading my second sprite class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, flappy-bird-clone

im creating a flappy bird game and after making the pipe sprite class my game is just extremely slow and unplayable i delete the class and its normal its driving me crazy can someone help please

```
import pygame
import time
from pygame.locals import *



pygame.init()
WIDTH =600
HEIGHT =650
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT))

run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
background_img = pygame.image.load('img/bg.png')
ground_img = pygame.image.load('img/ground.png')
ground_scroll = -10
flying = False
game_over = False
pipe_gap = 140

class Bird(pygame.sprite.Sprite) :
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.images = []
        self.index = 0
        self.speed = 0
        for num in range(1,3):
            imag = pygame.image.load(f'img/bird{num}.png')
            self.images.append(imag)
        self.image = self.images[self.index]
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = [x,y]
        self.vel = 0
        self.clicked = False



    def update(self) :
        if flying== True  :
            self.vel +=0.5
            if self.vel > 8:
                self.vel = 8
            if self.rect.bottom < 530:
                self.rect.y += int(self.vel)
        if game_over == False:
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] ==1 and self.clicked== False :
                self.clicked = True
                self.vel =-10
                self.rect.y += int(self.vel)



            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0  :
                self.clicked = False

            self.speed+=1
            self.ceiling = 7
            if self.speed > self.ceiling :
                self.speed = 0
                self.index+=1
                if self.index >= len(self.images):
                    self.index =0

            self.image = self.images[self.index]
            self.image=pygame.transform.rotate(self.images[self.index],self.vel *-2)
        else:
            self.image=pygame.transform.rotate(self.images[self.index],-180)

class Pipe(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load('img/pipe.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        if pos == -1 :
            pygame.transform.flip(self.image,False,True)
            self.rect.bottomleft = [x,y]
        else:
            self.rect.topleft = [x,y]


bird_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
pipe_group = pygame.sprite.Group()

flappy = Bird(100,320)

bird_group.add(flappy)

while run :

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    if game_over == False  :
        ground_scroll -=4
        if abs(ground_scroll) >= 35 :
            ground_scroll = 0
        btm_pipe = Pipe(300,250,1)
        top_pipe = Pipe(300,250,-1)
        bird_group.add(btm_pipe)
        bird_group.add(top_pipe)


    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and flying == False and game_over==False:
        flying = True
    if flappy.rect.bottom >530 :
        game_over = True
        flying= False



    clock.tick(60)
    screen.blit(background_img,(0,-230))
    screen.blit(ground_img,(ground_scroll,530))
    bird_group.draw(screen)
    bird_group.update()
    pygame.display.update()
```

im creating a flappy bird game and after making the pipe sprite class my game is just extremely slow and unplayable i delete the class and its normal its driving me crazy can someone help please

Comment: Events needs to be handled in the event loop, not after the event loop.

Comment: i indented the event and its  still freezing but it changed somehow still the problem remains

Answer (score -1):

You run your game at 60 frames per second. That means you create 120 Pipe instances per second. That also means you load the pipe image 120 times per second.

You should only load the image once, only create Pipe instances when they should actually spawn (like once per second or something like that), and kill those instances once they leave the screen (or simply move them to the right instead of creating new instances).